# Ruby multiline block without do end

Tags: ruby

I’m a beginner in Ruby, so I’m sorry to ask something so simple, but is there anything wrong with this code –

```
3.upto(9) {
  print "Hello"
  puts " World"
}
```

or

```
3.upto(9) { |n|
  print "Hello "
  puts n
}
```

It works well enough, but most of the code samples I see use the syntax of

```
3.upto(9) do |n|
  print "Hello "
  puts n
end
```

is it just the convention to only use curly braces for single statements?  Coming from C/C# the first seems more natural to me, but when in Rome!

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Ruby Block Syntax Error](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6854283/), [Code block passed to `each` works with brackets but not with `do`-`end` (ruby)](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6718340/), [Block definition - difference between braces and `do`-`end` ?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6179442/), [Using `do` block vs brackets `{}`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2122380/), [What is the difference or value of these block coding styles in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/533008/) and [Ruby block and unparenthesized arguments](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/420147/).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between the two syntaxes. `{ }` are higher precedence than `do ... end`. Thus, the following will pass `bar` and a block to method `foo`:

```
foo bar do ... end
```

while the following will pass a block to `bar`, and the result of that to `foo`:

```
foo bar { ... }
```

So your examples will act the same. However, if you left the parentheses off:

```
> 3.upto 9 { 
  puts "Hi" 
}
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):82: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting $end
3.upto 9 { 
          ^
    from (irb):82
    from :0

> 3.upto 9 do 
    puts "Hi" 
  end
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
=> 3
```

So, `{ }` are more likely to catch you up if you leave off parentheses in Ruby, which is fairly common; for this reason, and because Ruby conditionals and other control constructs all use `end` as a delimiter, people usually use `do ... end` for multi-line code blocks that come at the end of a statement.

However, `{ }` is frequently use in places where `do ... end` would be cumbersome, for instance, if you are chaining several methods together which take blocks. This can allow you to write short, one line little blocks which can be used as part of a method chain.

```
> [1,2,3].sort{|x,y| y<=>x}.map{|x| x+1}
=> [4, 3, 2]
```

Here's an example to illustrate this difference:

```
def foo arg
  if block_given?
    puts "Block given to foo"
    yield arg
  else
    puts "No block given to foo"
    arg
  end
end


def bar
  if block_given?
    puts "Block given to bar"
    yield "Yielded from bar"
  else
    puts "No block given to bar"
  end
  "Returned from bar"
end

irb(main):077:0> foo bar { |arg| puts arg }
Block given to bar
Yielded from bar
No block given to foo
=> "Returned from bar"
irb(main):078:0> foo bar do |arg| puts arg end
No block given to bar
Block given to foo
Returned from bar
=> nil
```

Comment: "However, {} can be used in circumstance in which do cannot, for instance, if you are chaining several methods together which take blocks." That's not true. `do` can be used perfectly well with chaining. `[1,2,3].map do |x| x+1 end.each do |x| puts x end` works fine.

Comment: @sepp2k You're right about that case; I was mistaken. I've updated my answer to indicate that that case is simply a matter of style.

Comment: 2 1/2 years later and this is a great answer, v helpful.

Comment: 13 years later; still great! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It's just convention.

Comment: in particular, the convention is to us do syntax for multiline, curlies for single line... but see the answer about precedence for a more through answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's [seamless](https://github.com/michaeledgar/seamless). From the `README`:

> Python allows you to signal the end of a code block with indentation. Ruby suffers from an extremely verbose and tedious block terminator, "end". Much like Lisps end up with dozens of close-parens, Ruby files that use modules and classes heavily end up with a plethora of "ends" that just aren't necessary.
>
> Write a Ruby file, but skip all the "ends". Line up your code blocks like in Python. Then just call it 'your_file.rbe', require 'seamless', and require 'your_file'. Seamless does the rest.
>
> Should this ever see widespread use? I don't know. But it's pretty fun!