# ruby: using blocks as normal (inline) expressions?

Tags: ruby

Looking for a little wisdom from fellow Rubyists. For a while now, I've used the following for convenience in some of my applications, and I'm wondering if there's a language feature I'm just missing:

```
class Object
  def as_block
    yield
  end
end
```

There are other uses, but the normal case for me is a conditional assignment that requires a little non-trivial logic. Two obvious ways to do this:

```
# via a second method:
def foo
  @foo ||= set_foo
end

# via conditional logic:
def foo
  if @foo
    @foo
  else
    # do complicated stuff
  end
end
```

Both of these approaches seem kind of ugly: in the first case, #set_foo seems extraneous, and the second just looks kind of nasty. So, instead, I like this:

```
def foo
  @foo ||= as_block do
    # do complicated stuff
  end
end
```

The problem here (aside from monkey patching Object) is that it's really a dependency (on the monkey patch) that looks like a language feature. That is, something like this really shouldn't be in (say) a Rails initializer---it seems like it should be in a gem, so the dependency can be managed correctly. Then I'm packaging an entire gem to run five lines of code to monkey patch Object...

So, my questions:
 1. Anyone else use this, or something like it?
 2. Has the Ruby team ever considered including something like this by default? It seems like a really easy way to use blocks as plain old expressions, but it's not there (as far as I know) which makes me wonder if there's some reason for not including it, or...
 3. Is there already some better way of doing this that I'm just unaware of?

Thanks!

-E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [lambda](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/34-lambdas-and-blocks-in-ruby/lessons/77-lambdas-in-ruby):

```
def foo
  @foo ||= lambda do
    # do complicated stuff
  end.call
end
```

Note that it is important to call the lambda to actually execute the expression, ie

```
def foo
  @foo ||= lambda do
    # do complicated stuff
  end
end
```

will return a lambda rather than your evaluated expression.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is `begin ... end`. This isn't the same thing as a `block` or `Proc`, as it's not an object you can pass around or a closure which creates a new scope, but it should serve your purpose just fine:

```
def foo
  @foo ||= begin
    # do complicated stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the begin/end approach---actually, the first few times I ran into this, that's what I used. My complaint is that it's... well, it's broken from both semantic and style perspectives. First, when I'm reading code, begin/end constructs that aren't trapping exceptions don't look right. More importantly, begin/end blocks have weird properties; see, e.g., http://blog.newrelic.com/2014/11/13/weird-ruby-begin-end/

Comment: @Erik I'm not sure why you think `begin ... end` doesn't look right while `as_block do ... end` does. IMO, this is one of the main reasons for using a `begin ... end` block, the other being exception handling. The special casing for creating a `do while` construct is indeed unfortunate, but it's really only a problem in that one case, and as long as you don't use it intentionally you're not going to run into that problem anyway. (E.g. Why would you write `begin ... end while <condition>` when you really meant just meant `while <condition>; ... end` in the first place?)

Comment: @Ajedi32, I did some looking around at this and it's true, it's not as problematic as I thought earlier. I'm not sure why, but like I said, my brain reads that looking for an ensure statement. Interesting discussion of it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279217/are-there-unintended-consequences-of-rubys-begin-end-without-rescue-use

Comment: @Erik Well, one person in the comments of the answer you linked suggested parenthesis as an alternative if you don't like `begin ... end`. Personally though, I prefer to avoid parenthesis for multi line expressions like this.

Comment: @Ajed32---Yeah, I'm not wild about parens there either. I'm going to do a little more research into the begin/end style---I may owe you an apology! I'll post back here.

Comment: @Erik No apology necessary. I don't take criticisms of the semantic features of Ruby personally. ;-)